# CSS for position absolute child div to be shown outside relative parent div

Tags: html, css

I have following html structure. I would like to show the "green" colored absolute div on top of "container" div.

```html
<h4>
  CSS Position Issue
</h4>
<div id="container" style="overflow: auto;height:55px;width:200px;border:3px solid blue;position:relative">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div style=";border:1px solid blue;">
        <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red;">
          if there is some really long content here, it will cause overflow, but the green box will not
          <div style="position:absolute; z-index:-1; left: 60px; top:0; height: 220px; width: 120px; background: green;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Below is the output of this.

[image]

I would like to show the green colored absolute div( which is inside of parent div) to be shown outside of parent "container" div.

Below is the desired output screenshot.

[image]

I am looking for pure css solution no scripting at all.

Comment: parent must be in position relative, and top:0

Comment: create a parent div of `#container` and set it `position: relative`. also remove positioning from `#container`.

Comment: What do you mean by outside? Above the container, below, next to it. Or do you want to the green to display on top like if you add `z-index: 1;` to the green box.

Comment: @Huelfe your solution is working, Could you please explain the reason as how extra parent div solved this issue?

Comment: @Gezzasa above the container so that it wont be cropped by container height and width so green should take its given height and width.

Comment: Your absolute positioned element is restricted by the relative element. So your element can't get over it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `overflow` of `#container` to `initial` could solve your issue. check below snippet for reference.

```css
#container {
  overflow: ;
  height: 55px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  position: relative
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.parent {
  height: auto;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 60px;
  top: 0;
  height: 220px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<h4>
  CSS Position Issue
</h4>
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="border">
        <div class="parent">
          if there is some really long content here, it will cause overflow, but the green box will not
          <div class="child">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't get what is your exact issue is, be more clear..But still you can try this.

```html
<h4>CSS Position Issue</h4>
    <div id ="container" style="overflow: auto; height: 55px; width: 200px; border: 3px solid blue;position:relative">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
                    <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red;">
                        if there is some really long content here, it will cause overflow, but the green box will not
                        <div style="position:absolute; z-index:-1; left: 0px; top:0; height: 220px; width: 120px; background: green;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Hope this will help you.